# What is the heaviest part of a rocket engine?

Tags: engines

I'm trying to understand how much different parts of a rocket engine weigh. For example, according to Wikipedia, [Merlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Merlin) engine weighs 470 kg, of which 70 kg is the turbopump. How is the remaining 400 kg break out? I'm guessing the broad categories could be:

1. Turbopump(s)
2. Combustion chamber
3. Nozzle
4. Plumbing
5. Thrust frame
6. Swing assembly

Totally understand that this breakdown might vary greatly for different engines, but if someone knows directional numbers for different types of engines (turbopump vs. staged combustion vs. expander cycle, maybe on an example of real engines - e.g. Merlin, RL10 etc.), would appreciate the info!

Comment: Two more components: thrust frame (keeps the parts together and transfers load to the rocket) and swing assembly (hydraulic tilt mechanism for thrust vectoring). The RD-191 and RD-193 are interesting in that regard, as they differ only in the presence/absence of thrust vectoring.

Comment: @RainerP. - thanks! Updated.

Comment: btw, very interesting info on RD-191/193 - seems like the swing assembly weight was over 300kg or about 15% of the mass.

Comment: @RainerP. surprised the swing assy is considered part of the engine.

Comment: This link is full of fantastic design info, although no weight data:   https://everydayastronaut.com/raptor-engine/

Comment: That is an interesting question, I looked for a list of the components for the SSME (RS-25) on my page and only came up with the total weight of the SSME:
https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer to your question:
The Saturn F1 engine weighed 18,000 pounds
The Space Shuttle SSME weighs ABOUT 7,000 pounds
See https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/SSME_MPS_Info/RSS-8559-1-1-1-19990041880.pdf
This is a chart of the weight of the turbopumps, out of the powerhead, pumps, plumbing and nozzle I think the nozzle would weigh the most as a single component (depends on how you break it down):
[image]